# How to upgrade Ontap version of unsupported netapp arrays?

Tags: upgrade, ontap

I am supporting netapp arrays which are already out of support but I need to upgrade the current ontap version. Any tips on how can I proceed without vendor support

I used ActiveIQ to validate the expected ontap version for the array.

Answer (score 1):

You may download the updated version from their website. [1]  Their is a guide on how to execute the upgrade.[2]. Just take note that the upgrade process can have downtime and risks so make sure you backup for disaster recovery.

[1] https://mysupport.netapp.com/site/downloads

[2] https://docs.netapp.com/us-en/ontap/upgrade/index.html